# appending anchor in flask template using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flask

I have a table in a flask template, I am trying to append anchor to it using JavaScript:

Table:

```
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-responsive mb-0 table-hover">
            <thead class="scroll-x">
                
            </thead>
            <tbody id='downloadPredictions'>
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$('#downloadPredictions').append("<td><a class='btn btn-primary' href='{{ url_for('download_corrected_file', dataset_id=dataset_id) }}'><i class='fa fa-download faicon' aria-hidden='true' title='Download'></i> Download Predictions</a></td>")
```

It sends following url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/%7B%7B%20url_for(
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong in href while appending anchor.
Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your JS .Make sure to use the correct quotation marks

```
$('#downloadPredictions').append("<td><a class='btn btn-primary' href='{{ url_for('download_corrected_file', dataset_id=dataset_id) }}'><i class='fa fa-download faicon' aria-hidden='true' title='Download'></i> Download Predictions</a></td>")
```

Should be

```
$('#downloadPredictions').append(`<td><a class='btn btn-primary' href="{{ url_for('download_corrected_file', dataset_id=dataset_id) }}"><i class='fa fa-download faicon' aria-hidden='true' title='Download'></i> Download Predictions</a></td>`)
```

Comment: You are right, however still it says: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/%7B%7B%20url_for('download_predictions',%20dataset_id=dataset_id)%20%7D%7D`
I think it should not add %7B in beginning and %7D in the end.

Comment: I suspect that your JS is not processed by Flask/Jinja2. Can you try embedding the JavaScript in your Jinja2 template wrapped inside a `<script>` tag?

Comment: Actually I need to put it in the success function of an ajax call.